# Want to upload audio to sound cloud via my server, how can i check to upload songs only from External storage directory

Tags: java, android, http, audio, upload

Using a button i want to upload an audio to soundcloud via my server from my phone External storage directory.How can i get the songs from external storage directory. How i will get the path from external storage and upload to server using http post.

I want to check the formats of mp3,mp4,amr audios.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          mDbHelper = new GinfyDbAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_audiogallery);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnuplaod);
        btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
        //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();   


        mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID4) 
                                                : null;

       registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();

       //for speech to text and recording purpose           
       setButtonHandlers();
       enableButtons(false);

       mp = new MediaPlayer();  

    }


  private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {


      confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            Toast.makeText(Uploadaudiogallery.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish(); 
        }

      });


  upload .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getFromSdcard();

        }

        public void getFromSdcard()
        {
            File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory())
                {
                    listFile = file.listFiles();
                   String[] Patternmp3 = {".3gp",".mp3",".amr",".mp4" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternmp3)){
                            f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                      }

                    }

                }
        }
  });
  }
```

How can i get the audio files with the format and how can i get the path to send to the server to upload .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a song you need to get the path of the audio file in external storage directory

```
String[] extensions = { ".mp3",".mp4",".MP3",".MP4"};
```

Then

```
String rootpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
// get the path of external storage directory
getAllAudioFilePath(rootpath);
```

Then loop through the folders and get the path of the files that matches the extension

```
private void getAllAudioFilePath(String rootFolder) {
    File file = new File(rootFolder);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    loadAllImages(f.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                        if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(extensions[i])) {
                            Log.i("Song files paths....",""+f.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Once you have the path of the files you can use the same to upload to a server by executing a http post.

Also don't forget to add read permission in the manifest file

Comment: after getting the path,is it automatically select the song ah?after selecting the song how can i take the title name of the song and how can i send the file path to asynctask using string

Comment: @KarthickM not path here is static. Display all audio file name is list. on item click get the path and upload